# React constructor isn't called when update a prop from parent component

Tags: reactjs, constructor, jsx

I have a "ChoiceBox", i need a chevron (arrow pointing up) rotate 180 deg, but I've been trying changing the value of the prop which manage the state of the chevron:

**ChoiceBox Component render method**

```
    render() {
        let animation = this.state.dropActive? "animation-active":"animation-unactive";
            return (
            <div className="region-choice"
                onClick = {()=>{
                    this.setState({dropActive:!this.state.dropActive}); 
/*HERE I set the dropmenu and chevron active*/
                }}
            >
                <div className="region-choice__selection ">Filter by Region 
/*HERE I SET THE VALUE*/
                    <Chevron chevronDownDirection={this.state.dropActive} ></Chevron> 
                </div>
                <div ref={this.dropDownOptions} className={"region-choice__options "+ animation} > {/* hidden absolute */}
                    <div className="options__option option-africa">Africa</div>
                    <div className="options__option option-africa">America</div>
                    <div className="options__option option-africa">Asia</div>
                    <div className="options__option option-africa">Europe</div>
                    <div className="options__option option-africa">Oceania</div>
                </div>
            
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Then i call the Chevron Tag, it's okey, the `chevronDownDirection` property is given to Chevron constructor into `props` :

```
class Chevron extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            chevronDownDirection: props.chevronDownDirection,
        }
    }
    render(){
        let chevronActive = this.state.chevronDownDirection?"chevron--active":"";
        return (
            <div className={"chevronD " + chevronActive}>
                <div className="chevron__left"></div>
                <div className="chevron__right"></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

When I click the choice box, the value of the state for the dopMenu y Chevron is inverted, and the `setState()` internally call to `render()`, and it shall re-render the Chevron, but it only calls to the `render()` method, the constructor is no used, so the value of the state is not modified, and the `state.chevronDownDirection` in `Chevron Component` always is false. (I debugged it, and the breakpoint doesn't stop in a contractor when I clicked).

So how can change that? Or Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: In a class component, the component is only instantiated (the constructor called) once. In this case you want to use the `componentDidUpdate` method to capture the subsequent updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now if you are changing the props of a component the constructor won't be called again, now if you just want to use the value you can use props directly else you can use "[static getDerivedStateFromProps()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)" if u want to use state

```
class Chevron extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            
        }
    }
    render(){
        let chevronActive = this.props.chevronDownDirection?"chevron--active":"";
        return (
            <div className={"chevronD " + chevronActive}>
                <div className="chevron__left"></div>
                <div className="chevron__right"></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

or

```
class Chevron extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            chevronDownDirection: false,
        }
    }

static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  if(nextProps.chevronDownDirection !== prevState.chevronDownDirection){
      return {
       chevronDownDirection:nextProps.chevronDownDirection
       }
    }
  else return null

}
 render(){
        let chevronActive = this.state.chevronDownDirection?"chevron--active":"";
        return (
            <div className={"chevronD " + chevronActive}>
                <div className="chevron__left"></div>
                <div className="chevron__right"></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, i forgot that I can use ‘props‘ too, thanks bro